# How can I listen to a TAB key pressed/typed in Java?

Tags: java, focus, traversal, keylistener, keyevent

```
    private void jTextField1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)
    {
        //cant capture my TAB?
        System.out.print(evt.getKeyChar());

    }
```

What is the simplest way in an java gui to capture the tab key without doing using the focus listening technique?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**VK_TAB** is the tab constant.

However: `No Tab key-pressed or key-released events are received by the key event listener. This is because the focus subsystem consumes focus traversal keys, such as Tab and Shift Tab.`

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

To solve this, apply the following to the component that is firing the key events (e.g., the TextArea):

`.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false)`

Using this method, you must then handle focus traversal explicitly.  Alternatively, the  [KeyEventDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/KeyEventDispatcher.html) class can be used to pre-listen to all key events.

Answer (score 0):

In case of editable JComboBox, this one worked for me:

```
    txt.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, Collections.emptySet());
    txt.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {

        }
       }
    });
```