# Why is control TAB keystroke not working?

Tags: java, swing, keystroke

Following is my code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Test {
    private int selected = 0;

    public Test() {

        JLabel[] lables = new JLabel[] { new JLabel("Lable1"),
                new JLabel("Label2") };
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        contentPane.add(lables[0]);
        contentPane.add(lables[1]);
        frame.pack();

        contentPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control TAB"), "next");
        Action action = new AbstractAction("next") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                selected++;
                Arrays.stream(lables).forEach(
                        l -> l.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY));
                lables[selected % 2].setForeground(Color.BLACK);

                System.out.println(selected);
                contentPane.revalidate();
                contentPane.repaint();
            }
        };
        contentPane.getActionMap().put("next", action);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();

    }
}
```

But when I press control TAB, nothing happens. But when if I change the code to something like `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control K"), "next");` the control K keystorke changes the foreground color.

What am I doing wrong? Is the "control Tab" reserved for some purpose? If so, how can I change that behaviour so that I can bind that keystroke to my action?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I listen to a TAB key pressed/typed in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275204/how-can-i-listen-to-a-tab-key-pressed-typed-in-java)

Comment: put `frame.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);` as per the duplicate link

Comment: @Madhan Thanks for the answer Madhan, but my question involves the control key as well. The linked issue and its answer talks about the TAB and SHIFT TAB keys. I want to make sure that answer applies to CTRL TAB as well.

Comment: just add the above mentioned line in your code and it will work