# How to listen for tab press in a Java console application

Tags: java

Is it possible to have something that listens for tab press?
Specifically I would like to auto complete, on tab press, I know people have done it before. I of course would like to do this all without any external libraries. The java base I am currently using is Java 1.8, so no complications there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I listen to a TAB key pressed/typed in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275204/how-can-i-listen-to-a-tab-key-pressed-typed-in-java)

Comment: Moved from answer to comment, you might also want to check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037576/how-do-i-check-if-the-user-is-pressing-a-key

Comment: It is not a duplicate as that question is about JFrame this is console application. Also I found a way to do it like 30 minutes after this thread, and it would work perfectly, if I was to make a packet for the list.