# Why won't my Java Swing Keybinds work with Tab but they work fine with Space?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I'm making a game that uses Java Swing's keybinding. In that game, all the keybinds work fine, until I swap tabs and tab back in (tabs here referring to windows and not the tab key), in which case certain keys (most notably the tab key) no longer work (many other of the other keys work fine).

I made a new test class to try and debug this, but it just created a new problem where I wrote identical keybinds for tab and space, but only space works. I believe it has to do with the tab key already having a default keybind with JFrame since before, I had solved an issue with space not working due to JButton having a default space keybind. So here, I tried to unbind the tab key before adding my keybind, but it still didn't work. Here is the base code I have right now:

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.sound.midi.Instrument;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiChannel;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.midi.Synthesizer;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class test1 {
    
    static JFrame frame;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new JFrame();
        
        int IFW = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
        
        
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//      frame.pack();
        
        
        JRootPane rootpane = frame.getRootPane();
        
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        rootpane.getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0), "space");
        rootpane.getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0), "space");
        rootpane.getActionMap().put("space", new spaceAction());
    }
    
    public static class Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        
        public Frame() {
            super("Test");
        }
        
    }
    
    public static class spaceAction extends AbstractAction {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("a");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Here, pressing space prints "a", but pressing tab doesn't.

I tried looking up solutions to this, but most of the fixes involved using `JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`, which I do use here.

Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I listen to a TAB key pressed/typed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275204/how-can-i-listen-to-a-tab-key-pressed-typed-in-java) Next time please do a search on subject that you need help with.

Comment: `Frame extends JFrame` why was this class included but never used in the rest of the code?